# 1 ViewController Screen For Multiple ViewController Class File

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have multiple `UITableViewController` which just have different data, then I just have a `UIViewController` screen on `UIStoryboard` as template.

How to working with template screen?

How to set `IBOutlet` and `IBAction`? Because can only set to one `UIViewController` class to a `UIViewController` screen.

Before, I just copy paste the `UIViewController` screen for each `UIViewController`.

Comment: Regarding your question, you can find multiple answers in stackoverflow that have already been answered. Please refer them and then only ask your question. Here's an example of the implementation that you have been asking for.https://gist.github.com/mchirico/50cdb07d20b1b0f73d7c

Comment: Are you trying to design CustomCell or CustomView for your screen ?